# JavaFx Application Window Unresponsive

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm running a javaFx application which loads a graph onto the canvas. When I run some graph manipulation algorithms, it takes a lot of time especially for large graphs. During this calculation the application window *greys out* and becomes unresponsive which isn't really a good way how the end users using the application should see it.

So I was wondering if there is a better way to show the users that the application will be unresponsive till the time the process is finished.

Comment: Run the computation in a background thread. Maybe start by reading the [`Task` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Comment: @James_D - cool, I'll check it out. Thanks!